# Как войти в gii?

Tags: yii

Раскоментила в main.php следующее:

```
'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'123',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
    ),
```

и вот это:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Набираю в адресной строке http://localhost/appstan/index.php?r=gii - выхожу на главную страницу. Как оказаться в самом gii?

Comment: А если просто http://localhost/appstan/gii ?

Comment: так тоже не пашет. нашла все-таки как:
http://localhost/appstan/index.php/gii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://localhost/appstan/index.php/gii